# Suppose that zero is a lebesgue point of an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^1)$. Prove f(o)= $ \lim_{r\to0^+}\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^rf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that zero is a Lebesgue point of an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^1)$. How would one prove
$$
\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^rf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\quad\text{?}
$$

Comment: do you mean "$=f(0)$"?

Answer (score 1):

By the integral triangle inequality, 
$$\left|f(0)-\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^rf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \right|
=\left|\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^r(f(0)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x \right|
\le \frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^r|f(0)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x \tag1
 $$
As $r\to 0^+$, the righthand side of (1) tends to $0$ by the [definition of a Lebesgue point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point). Therefore, the lefthand side tends to $0$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

For any Lebesgue point we can observe that in this case this reduces to
$$
f(x+r\theta(x,r))\to f(x)=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac1{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
If $0$ is a Lebesgue point, then;
Choosing a sequence $r\to0^+$  so that $x+r$ and $x-r$ are rational numbers
and the condition says that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to0^+}⁡\frac1{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^rf(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac1{2r}\times0\\[4pt]
&=0\\[10pt]
&=f(0)
\end{align}
$$
Hence,we have $f(0)$,when $r\to0^+$
$$
f(0)=\lim_{r\to0^+}⁡\frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^rf(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Somehow, your formatting got meesed up (maybe from cut and paste). You might want to correct this. Also, it is best to use [LaTex/MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Regards

Comment: I have attempted to $\LaTeX$ify your answer. Please check to make sure I got it right.